# Checkstyle's SimplifyBooleanExpressionCheck

Tags: java, checkstyle

I have an expression like

```
MyRequest request = someObject.getRequest();
boolean isInitialRequest = initialRequest == null ? true : false;
```

Unfortunately checkstyle does not like that. How can I simplify this to satisfy checkstyle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add `? true : false`. The condition `initialRequest == null` already returns true or false.

This is the same but in a shorter version:

```
MyRequest request = someObject.getRequest();
boolean isInitialRequest = initialRequest == null;
```